# Linux: How to break a large file into smaller files?

Tags: linux, tar, files

I have a giant file (>20 gigs) sitting on my source machine and I need to transfer it to my target machine.  For the purposes of this question, let's assume that I do not have network connectivity between the two machines.

I need to break this file into a series of smaller files, write the smaller files to DVD(s), then re-assemble everything on the target machine.

Both source and destination machines are Linux boxes.  Is there a way to accomplish this using `tar`?  I have a feeling that I need to use the `--multi-volume` parameter.  What are my options?

**I need to be able to specify the size of the volume files, in order to make sure that each one will fit onto a single DVD.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the split command.

`split -b 22 m newfile.txt new` would split the file "newfile.txt" into three separate files called newaa, newab and newac each file the size of 22 MB.

Comment: Be careful of creating the prefix "new" that you share with the original file "newfile.txt". Now when you try to do `cat new* > newfile.txt` it will blow up!

Comment: @RobertMartin Good catch!

Answer (score 6):

Other answers have covered `split` to combine them to one master file you just use `cat`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done easily using [split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split), which should be already available in the base of your distribution since it is part of [gnu coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).

Answer (score 0):

split -b 4000000000 file_name

It will create each file of 4 GB